# Limited IList<> implementation?

Tags: c#, arrays, ilist

I'm doing some work with stats, and want to refactor the following method :

```
public static blah(float[] array)
{
    //Do something over array, sum it for example.
}
```

However, instead of using float[] I'd like to be using some kind of indexed enumerable (to use dynamic loading from disk for very large arrays for example).
I had created a simple interface, and wanted to use it.

```
public interface IArray<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    T this[int j] { get; set; }
    int Length { get; }
}
```

My problem is :

- float[] only inherits IList, not IArray, and AFAIK there's no way to change that.
- I'd like to ditch IArray and only use IList, but my classes would need to implement many methods like `Add`, `RemoveAt` although they are fixed size
- And then my question : how can float[] implement IList whereas it doesn't have these methods ?

Any help is welcome.
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> float[] only inherits IList, not IArray, and AFAIK there's no way to change that.

Array of T also implements `IList<T>` and others (but these don't always show in tools, several aspects of Array as special cased by the runtime).

> I'd like to ditch IArray and only use IList, but my classes would need to implement many methods[...]

This is true, but such implementation is quite quick to do (and should you only need non-modifying operations, you can just throw a `NotImplementedException` from modifying methods).

In practice in only takes a few minutes to do, and your implementation should be reusable. Also there are types like `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` to help avoid a lot of this work.

> And then my question : how can float[] implement IList whereas it doesn't have these methods ?

A type can explicitly implement interface methods. They are not directly members of the type, but casting to the interface (or reflection) will allow access. This allows a typed collection to implement `IEnumerator.Current` (returning `Object`) while also providing a `Current` property that returns the correct type.

Comment: think you mean explicit, not implicit

Comment: @Sekhat: indeed I did. Corrected.

Comment: Hum, thanks, you learned me the difference between and explicit/implicit interface method implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, `float[] array` does implement `IList<float>`:

```
var floats = new[] { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.5f };
var list = (IList<float>)floats;
```

This is per [19.6](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334:_19.6_Arrays_and_the_generic_IList_interface):

> A one-dimensional array `S[]` implements the interface `System.Collections.Generic.IList<S>` (`IList<S>` for short) and its base interfaces. Accordingly, there is an implicit conversion from `S[]` to `IList<S>` and its base interfaces.

Comment: I know that, my question is how can it be that it implements IList<float> and ICollection without implementing Add, RemoveAt and these other methods from ICollection/IList ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing the following stuff :
    public class IArrayWrapper : IArray
    {
        private float[] innerArray;

```
    public IArrayWrapper(float[] array)
    {
        innerArray = array;
    }

    public static implicit operator float[](IArrayWrapper wrapper)
    {
        return wrapper.innerArray;
    }

    public static implicit operator IArrayWrapper(float[] array)
    {
        return new IArrayWrapper(array);
    }

    public IEnumerator<float> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<float>) innerArray).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return innerArray.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public float this[int j]
    {
        get { return innerArray[j]; }
        set { innerArray[j] = value; }
    }

    public int Length
    {
        get { return innerArray.Length; }
    }
}
```

I'm not very proud of it, but I think implicit operators should solve my problem... hopefully.